# Show that $|Corr(Y,Z)| \le |Corr(\hat Y,Z)|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y,Z \in L^2, \hat Y =E(Y|Z)$. Show that $$|Corr(Y,Z)| \le |Corr(\hat Y,Z)|$$

Here is my work:
$|Corr(\hat Y,Z)|=\frac{|Cov(\hat Y,Z)|}{\sqrt {Var(\hat Y)}\sqrt {Var(Z)}}$
and $|Corr( Y,Z)|=\frac{|Cov(Y,Z)|}{\sqrt {Var( Y)}\sqrt {Var(Z)}}$

Also, I know that $Cov(\hat Y,Z)|=|Cov(Y,Z)|$, so it suffices to show that $\sqrt {Var( Y)} \ge \sqrt {Var(\hat Y)} $ and this is where I got stuck.

Can anyone give me any hint or idea of how to prove this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) tells us:

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}(Y | X)] + \operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{E}[Y| X]) = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}(Y| X)] + \operatorname{Var}(\hat{Y})$$